# Use Javascript to add user-generated text to DOM as-is without using whitelist or blacklist

Tags: web-applications, xss, javascript

Currently, my code (uses jQuery) looks something like this and is completely vulnerable to XSS:

```
$.get('/api-endpoint', (data) => {
  $('body').html(`Body text: ${data['text']}`)
}
```

I don't want to install a blacklist, whitelist, or external library. The ideal solution would be a simple one-liner that tells Javascript to simply add `data['text']` without interpreting anything inside it.

---

Edit: Second case, slightly more complex:

```
$.get('/api-endpoint', (data) => {
  $('body').html(`<h1>Body text:</h1><br>${data['text']}`)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Don't treat it as HTML, treat is as text.

The underlying DOM API to treat a string as text is `textContent`, as opposed to `innerHTML` which would treat it like HTML. In jQuery, the `.text` method wraps this API.

```
$('body').text(`Body text: ${data['text']}`)
```

*Don't* use the `.html` method. It wraps the `innerHTML` API, with some extra code to ensure script tags are executed.

---

For a more-complex case, construct your DOM elements, and set the text content on the element you want. Or as in your code, if no single element wraps your text, use `document.createTextNode` to create a text node and append it.

```
$('body')
    .empty()
    .append(
        $('<h1>Body text:</h1>'),
        $('<br>'),
        document.createTextNode(data['text'])
    )
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/p3q1nr8t/)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I've shot myself in the foot... I've added an edit above to refine my question

Comment: @DavidTan I've added a more-complex example which creates the elements and text node to match your example.